# What is the difference between "catching a cold " and "catching cold"?

Tags: grammar

My aunt always used to tell me  "You'll catch cold if you go outside without wearing a jacket".

Why is this different if I were to say "You'll catch a cold if you go outside without wearing a jacket"?

To me, catching a cold makes more sense but I hear many people saying "catch cold"...

Comment: There's no difference IMO, I think it's just dialect.

Comment: The form without the definite article has been declining in use since the late 1930s according  to this Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catch+a+cold%2C+caught+a+cold%2C+catch+cold%2C+caught+cold&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccatch%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaught%20cold%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *catch cold* must be archaic where I'm from, I don't think I've ever heard it before!

Comment: Keep in mind that the overall idiom is nonsensical.  Why would one "catch" a cold -- isn't it more like the cold catches you?  Aside from flu and pneumonia I'm not able to think of any other illness that one commonly "catches".  Generally, one "gets" or "comes down with" other infectious diseases.  (The point being that the expression is very highly idiomatic, and hence not expected to follow "normal" syntax patterns.)

Answer (score 1):

**catch cold** has been used longer and does sound like older usage. The N-gram shows **its use has been declining since 1940**.  Although some people say there is a difference in meaning (one of them being "catch a disease" and the other just "the consequences of having been exposed to very cold temperature") I don't see any.

"Please close the window, or we'll all [catch cold."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/catch+cold)/a cold.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whether speakers are fully aware of it or not, ***catch cold***, and ***catch a cold*** potentially mean two different things.

*Catch a cold* refers to the common cold virus. But protracted exposure to cold - *catch cold* - can cause health problems well beyond the cold virus. In England there are typically 23,000 more deaths between December and March than in the rest of the year in total. This is due to cold.

*Influenza* can be a quite serious condition (many cases reported as flu are not flu at all - if you have real flu you feel quite ill*). There is a link between cold weather and heart attacks and pulmonary disease. Cold weather can cause thickening of the blood, an increase in blood pressure, and tightening of the airwaves. There is also the risk, in extreme cases of hypothermia.

***So quite apart from the risk of catching a cold; it is not a good idea to catch cold***

**Later edit:**

The different expressions each with a different meaning of *catching cold* and *catching a cold* are fully borne out by the OED. See below, the separate meaning 5b and 5c. of the mass noun and the count noun, respectively of - *cold*

> 5.b. As a mass noun: disease attributed to an excess of the quality of coldness within the body or part of the body, to a superfluity of cold
>   humours (esp. phlegm), or to exposure to low temperature; (in later
>   use) spec. acute and self-limited catarrhal illness of the upper
>   respiratory tract (cf. common cold n. at common adj. and adv. Special
>   uses 1). Orig. esp. in to take cold ; later esp. in to catch cold .
>
> c. As a count noun: an instance of such disease; spec. an acute and
>   self-limited episode of catarrhal illness of the upper respiratory
>   tract, often with sneezing, running of the eyes, sore throat, cough,
>   and slight fever, now known to be caused by any of numerous viruses
>   (cf. common cold n. at common adj. and adv. Special uses 1). Freq. in
>   to catch, get, have, or take a cold .

Comment: I don't think many native speakers would understand *catch cold* (no article) as  *protracted exposure to cold*.

Comment: @tunny Look in the OED.

Comment: I did look there. My earlier comment stands.

Comment: @tunny But when the older generation said 'put a coat on, you'll catch cold' I feel quite certain they were not speaking specifically about the common cold virus.

Comment: They may have done. It's possible some still do. I simply believe, as I said, that not many native speakers would understand it in that way. I have been unable to find any research on this, so I can present this thought only as an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Both are used. *Catch cold* is less commonly used. It is also much more likely to occur in speech than in non-dialogue writing.

Here is [the entry for *catch cold*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/catch+cold) as an idiom in TFD, which includes some examples of its use in classic literature.